# how to automatic save all terminal output to a log file?

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to save all my terminal output to a log file **automaticly**,
not like this

```
$ ls -al > file.txt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
script logfile
```

In the end of your session just type `exit`.

All your console output will be recorded to the file **logfile**.

Comment: Good ol' `script`